# Can we add/define Office 365 security group to be able to add/remove users from all the Teams

Tags: office-365, administration, groups, microsoft-teams, azure-ad

We have created a security group named `TeamsAdmin`, as follow:

[image]

and we want users inside this group to be able to add/remove members/owners from all the Teams entities we currently have:

[image]

so is this possible? and how? to define this security group as Teams admins for example?

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, we can't add a security group directly into Office 365 Group as a Member or Owner.

As a work around you can create a Dynamic Group.

> Microsoft Teams supports teams associated with Microsoft 365 groups by
> using dynamic membership. Dynamic membership enables the membership of
> a team to be defined by one or more rules that check for certain user
> attributes in Microsoft Entra ID. Users are automatically added or
> removed to the correct teams as user attributes change or users join
> and leave the tenant.

See the official documentation below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/dynamic-memberships

Comment: Note that `This feature requires a Microsoft Entra ID P1 license` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/groups-dynamic-membership

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, users will need **Microsoft Teams administrator** role to manage all Teams in the Microsoft 365 tenant.

I think you cannot assign such admin roles to Azure AD security groups, instead you will have to assign the Microsoft Teams administrator role to individual users.

Check below Microsoft official documentations for more information:

1. [About admin roles in the Microsoft 365 admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/about-admin-roles)
2. [Use Microsoft Teams administrator roles to manage Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/using-admin-roles)
3. [Manage teams in the Microsoft Teams admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-teams-in-modern-portal)
4. [Assign admin roles to Microsoft 365 user accounts with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/assign-roles-to-user-accounts-with-microsoft-365-powershell) - assign roles to multiple users (bulk operation) using PowerShell